# Window.innerHeight conflict with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I added bootstrap to an existing webpage. The Webpage uses Javascript for sizing content, so

```
var containerHeight = window.innerHeight - header - footer
```

is used a few times.

Since I added bootstrap, the height of the `<html>` is wrong (means a horizontal scroll bar appears) after the inital load/refresh of every page, where `window.innerHeight`is called.
The "extra" area is plain white, and the debbuging tool tells me, this is outside of the `<body>` and jsut part of the `<html>` area.

Any action (resizing the window, background events, really anything) resets the height to the correct 100% and the horizontal scroll bar disappears.

As soon as I comment the line with `window.innerHeight` out, the issue disappears. Just CALLING! the line causes the issue, even if the resulting value is not applied.

This works fine:

```
//var containerHeight = window.innerHeight - header - footer
//$('.someClass').css('height',containerHeight)
```

This doesn't

```
var containerHeight = window.innerHeight - header - footer
//$('.someClass').css('height',containerHeight)
```

(Same applies for `$(window).height()` btw )

How do I solve this without removing bootstrap.

Additionally I took out the bootstrap.js file, to test if there are any scripts in conflict.

I renamed the variables a few times, too see if they would in some way be in conflict with any bootstrap set variables...

I tested out `max-height=100%;` and things alike, but it didn't work for me.

The issue only occurs in IE9 as far as I know. Unfortunately I have to use this Browser, since my company has it as its standard browser.

I acquired the bootstrap files via NuGet-Package Manager, since I work with ASP.NET

Please let me know, if you need more information, I will be happy to provide them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I "brute-forced" through the bootstrap.css (commented out first half, checked, then second half and repeated for the remaining area)

As soon as I commented out this part:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 
 {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 1px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 }
```

The issue was solved.

If anyone can explain this to me, I will accept the according answer!